# Append new rows to DF

Tags: python, dataframe, selenium

I have this piece of code. I am trying to scrape some pages and in the end store the df into a csv-file. With print(jumboOrders) I can see the right information appearing on my screen. The problem is that it is not stored into the csv file. Can you help me with a solution?

```
orders_list = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0])
print(type(orders_list)) # output = <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

for PageNo in range(1, (NumOfPage)):
    try:
        #string = '//*[@id="create-user-form"]/div[3]/ul/li['+str(PageNo)+']'
        #print (string)
        nextpage = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, str('//*[@id="create-user-form"]/div[3]/ul/li['+str(PageNo)+']'))))
        JumboOrders = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]
        print(JumboOrders)
        orders_list.append(JumboOrders)
        nextpage.click()        
                    
    except:
        print("failed to go to next page", PageNo)  

orders_list.to_csv('orders_list.csv', sep = ';')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs in `orders_list.append(JumboOrders)`. The `.append()` method works a little bit differently for dataframes than it does for lists. That is, instead of appending to `orders_list` and overwriting the *existing* dataframe, your code returns a *new* dataframe object. `orders_list.to_csv('orders_list.csv', sep = ';')`, however, still refers to the original, non-appended, `orders_list` dataframe.

To solve this, instead of `orders_list.append(JumboOrders)`, you could do:

```
orders_list = orders_list.append(JumboOrders)
```

or, using `inplace`:

```
orders_list.append(JumboOrders, inplace=True)
```